# Retrieve data with child from Firebase Database and Populate Object Class using Kotlin

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin, data-retrieval, auto-populate

How can I retrieve data with child* from Firebase Database and populate an User object class.

Firebase example:

- users

  - uid : 131232

    - firstName : John
    - lastName : Doe
    - location

      - lat* : 15.2512312
      - lon* : -12.1512321
    - chats

      - -k1231* : true
      - -k1285* : true

and after having retrieved the data being able to use ie.: **User.firstName** or **User.location.lat** etc.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: To understand better, you want to query the database for all objects where `k1231` is eqaul to `true`?

Comment: My friend @Alex-Mamo, this is a Firebase Database model. I just want to query this User 1332 and cast it to the User.class object inside the app to work with the object. My main doubt is to know how to create the class User and the adapter to absorb all the items including the child "Chat" with its children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sam Stern mentioned in his answer, it's best to create a representation for each class separately. I'll write you the corresponding classes in Kotlin.

This is the `User` class:

```
class User (
    val firstName: String = "",
    val lastName: String = "",
    val userLocation: UserLocation? = null
)
```

And this is the `UserLocation` class:

```
class UserLocation (
        val lat: Int = 0,
        val lng: Int = 0
)
```

> to query this User 1332 and cast it to the User.class object

Please use the following lines of code:

```
val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
val rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
val uidRef = rootRef.child("users").child(uid)
val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        val user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User::class.java)
        Log.d(TAG, "Lat/Lng: " + user!!.userLocation!!.lat + ", " + user.userLocation!!.lng);
    }

    override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.message) //Don't ignore errors!
    }
}
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
```

In which the `uid` should hold a value like `131232`. The output in your logcat will be:

```
Lat/Lng: 15.2512312, -12.1512321
```

In the same way you can get: `user!!.firstName` and `user!!.lastName`.

Comment: Hi Dimitri! Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: Hey!!! Thank you very much @Alex-Mamo! It worked! Look what I got from my Log.d: "2018-11-07 01:14:07.971 22395-22395/com.app.firebaseusertest D/MainActivity: Lat/Lng: 15.2512312, -12.1512321". Your answer was really complete!

Comment: My friend @alex-mamo what about the list of chats in the node chat? In firebase denormalized db this is very common: to have the references of other nodes under  other node like: id = true.

Comment: This sounds as a new challenge which basically should be considered another question that cannot be answered in a comment or using only the data above. Iin order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question using a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so me and other users can help you.

Comment: Ok. Thank you my friend!

Comment: Is that retrieving data from the database though? or is it coming from the class?

Comment: @AdanVivero Yes, it's from the database,

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to create multiple custom classes:

```
class User {
  public String firstName;
  public String lastName;
  public UserLocation location;
}
```

...

```
class UserLocation {
   public double lat;
   public double lon;
}
```

Then you can deserialize the whole thing to `User`.

Comment: Thank you very much @Sam-Stern! I understood and I have used both suggestions in my app: from you and from @Alex-Mamo.

Comment: Hi @sam-stern! What about the UserChats class?